# Assembly Language 32-Bit Video Mode

Tags: assembly

I am starting to learn assembly language. I learned about the Video Modes in 8086/16-bit assembly language, I just want to how to implement those in 32-Bit assembly language.

In 16 bit assembly language,

```
mov ah,00h
mov al,10h
int 10h
```

gives you, 640x350 resolution

```
mov ah,09h
mov al, character-to-be-printed
mov bh,00h
mov bl, attrtibutes
mov cx,0001h
int 10h
```

prints a character with specific color,

I just want to know how to implement these codes in 32-bit.

Comment: The first thing you will want to do is edit and list what compiler you are working with. There are significant differences between them, and much of the direct BIOS calls for video modes has gone the way of the dinosaur in many of them.

Comment: What do you mean by _"implementing"_ a video mode? You need to provide a much clearer problem description.

Comment: By 32-bit do you mean running from within Windows operating system? If this is the case you can't do it directly, you need to use Windows API 1) Get Display Devices https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609.aspx 2) Get available modes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611.aspx 3) Change the resolution https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411.aspx  You then need to investigate calling Win32 APIs from assembly

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by `32-bit mode`. Are you using a 32-bit CPU in `real mode` or are you using a 32-bit CPU in `protected mode` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (`int 10h`) is DOS/BIOS API and it works only in 16-bit mode. You can use 32-bit registers with prefix but the processor or VM or V86 task is in 16-bit mode.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are trying to write an OS. Video is a complex topic, but you may look [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Category:Video) for start point.

Comment: I am trying to make an application that runs on console, but i want to adjust its resolution, add some color, write pixels on it just like in DOS. Is it possible?

Comment: @JayMarkParedesEstrera: If you want 16bit application - use your approach with `int10h`. If you want 32bit application, you need to create window (use `WinApi`) and operate on it. No other path which I'm aware of.

Comment: Most of the bios routine are only written for the 16 bit real address mode. And i prefer to boot a real DOS for using the (VBE 3-) Bios from the display device, but also a 16 bit DOS emulator "DOSBOX" for Windows exist. http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1